# Can an "abnormal" RAM stick interfere with the working sticks?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, computer-building

I have 4 8GB sticks of RAM in my machine and 3 are working fine. The forth is declared "abnormal" by my bios and only 4GB of the 8GB are recognized by my OS, giving me a total of 28GB of RAM.

I would like to know if the faulty stick could interfere with the 3 good ones in any way. An I better off removing the abnormal one and using the 24GB or should I leave it in?

Comment: Can I ask what on Earth you need 28GB of RAM for? What's the highest RAM usage that you've ever hit?

Answer (score 2):

If it interferes is really a matter of the hardware, what exactly "abnormal" means, and how it handles it. But, I can say without a doubt, I would not continue using it. Most RAM has a lifetime warranty, you likely could get it replaced. On the other hand, a change from 28 to 24GB is likely not something you're going to notice.

It is not worth sacrificing the stability of your system.